# Разбор вложенного массива с помощью рекурсии

Tags: php, массивы

Есть пример разбора массива с помощью рекурсии, но мне не совсем понятна логика. Получается после разбора возвращается переменная $mass(на 9 строке) уже в разобранном виде. Как так получилось? Почему массив разобран если все должно было записаться в переменную $val?

```php
function recurs($mass) {
    if (is_array($mass)) {
        $val = '';
        foreach ($mass as $str) {
            $val .= recurs($str);
        }
        return $val;
    } else {
        return $mass;
    }
}


$arr = array(array('1312'),'312312','312312');
echo recurs($arr);
```

Comment: Запустите с отладчиком и посмотрите как будет выполняться код. Неужели вас этому не обучают?

Answer (score 0):

В условии написано буквально следующее: если в переменной `$mass` передали именно массив, то... и в первых фигурных скобках рекурсивно обрабатывается этот массив с возможными вложенными в него массивами. Затем идёт иначе. То есть, иначе, если в переменной $mass передан не массив, возвращаем эту переменную. Не в разобранном виде, а просто интерпретируя эту переменную как строку. В случае `else {...}` с переменной ничего не делают, просто возвращают.